# Rails form on a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get each candidate belonging to a position have its own page. How do I implement this?

```rb
= form_for @vote do |f|
  - Position.includes(:candidates).order(:name).each do |position|
    = position.name
    - position.candidates.each do |candidate|
      = image_tag(candidate.image, :size => '50x50') if candidate.image.attached?
      = candidate.name
      = candidate.info
      = f.check_box :c_votes
      = f.submit "Submit"
```

When I use this code it creates a submit button for each candidate on the same page.

Comment: can you rephrase your question? not quite clear what exactly you want to do

Comment: as well add your relationships (what belongs to what)